# How to find documentation for specific version of nginx?

Tags: ssl, nginx, debian

On a Debian stable server, I use nginx installed from official debian repositories. It is currently version **1.10.3**.
Now, I need to get some information to correctly configure my websites with SSL and let's encrypt.

I want to understand if `ssl on` directive is mandatory in my server config file. I opened [official documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl), which say

> ```
> Syntax:   ssl on | off;
> Default:  
> ssl off;
> Context:  http, server
> ```
>
> This directive was made obsolete in version 1.15.0. The ssl parameter
>   of the listen directive should be used instead.

Ok, so `ssl on` is obsolete starting from nginx 1.15. But I'm still working with nginx 1.10. **Where can I find some official nginx documentation for older versions ?**

Comment: I don't know when `ssl on;` was deprecated - but the preferred solution is `listen 443 ssl;` which has been valid since 0.7.14 according to [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on https://nginx.org/2017.html version 1.10.3 went out on 2017-01-31

So I would just use the wayback machine to grab the page you link to but at that date, which gives you something like: https://web.archive.org/web/20170203141515/https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl
to take the first available snapshot after the date above.

You can then read there:

> Syntax:   ssl on | off;
>
> Default:
>
> ```
> ssl off;
> ```
>
> Context:  http, server
>
> Enables the HTTPS protocol for the given virtual server.
>
> ```
> It is recommended to use the ssl parameter of the listen directive instead of this directive.
> ```

Comment: Yeah, using archive.org for that purpose totally make sense. Thanks for the tip, I removed `ssl on` from all my server configs (i already used ssl option in `listen` directives.